# Issues with Ubuntu non-ISO-Hybrid iso images

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, iso

When I try to install Ubuntu from a USB drive after I added the latest ubuntu 15.10 iso image to the USB drive using Pendrivelinux I am getting this error:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: No such device
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

It seems that although the iso was added to a USB drive using a tool that is mainly made to do such process but Ubuntu is trying to mount the files on the CDROM while I am actually trying to install from a USB drive, after some reading I found out that the ISO files needs to be Hybrid ISO files in order to be able to use it from a USB drive and starting some later Ubuntu versions they are not producing these hybrid iso files anymore which is a bit strange since a lot of modern laptops now come without a CD/DVD drive

It seems that a number of the forums discussing the resolution for this issue are suggesting using the `isohybrid` Linux command which ignores the fact that some users might be actually installing Ubuntu for the first time (like myself) and all they have is a Windows system :(

Comment: This would be a good place to find out how to create the iso usb source in the correct way, but I believe they are assuming that the owner has a linux system already (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073)

Comment: First check the md5 sum of the iso - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows Then if the md5sum is ok try this - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: The md5 sum is ok without issues and the steps mentioned here using pendrivelinux universal installer is what I used, I believe either the iso file is not equipped to be written on a usb drive or the installer has an issue, still investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use Universal USB Installer? or another tool on PenDriveLinux... if that didn't work I suggest you use YUMI as it is what I use and it always* works

Comment: I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3, does your answer mean that the installer itself that created the USB image has an issue or the iso file itself, I was under the impression that the iso file itself has an issue because it is not a hybrid one

Comment: well if you used UUI then it should work so my best guess would be a corrupt ISO

Comment: The strange thing is that the same iso has worked using YUMI, so it seems a problem in the universal installer after all !

Comment: well then.... at least you got it working :p